# What is original Persian poem of Rumi for "The garden of the world has no limits, except in your mind"?

Tags: poetry, quote-source, persian-language, rumi

Does anyone know the Persian text for the below poem of Rumi?

> The garden of the world has no limits, except in your mind.

Source: [Quotable Quote on GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/472665-the-garden-of-the-world-has-no-limits-except-in).

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: This is a bad translation of a line from [ghazal 332](http://shamsrumi.com/molana/poem/ghazal/ghazal-332) in the [*Diwan-e Shams-e Tabrizi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwan-e_Shams-e_Tabrizi). A more accurate translation would be, “the house of love has no limits”.

This was hard to track down, because the original poem has neither “garden of the world” nor “except in your mind”, leaving us with only “has no limits” to go on! I hope to convince you that this is enough to identify the work.

If you search for the text in the post, then you’ll find that it is commonly given as the first part of this [longer quotation](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7368119-the-garden-of-the-world-has-no-limits-except-in):

> The garden of the world has no limits except in your mind. Its presence is more beautiful than the stars, with more clarity than the polished mirror of your heart.

This is just about recognizable as a bad translation of these lines from [ghazal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghazal) (ode) [number 332](http://shamsrumi.com/molana/poem/ghazal/ghazal-332) in the [*Diwan-e Shams-e Tabrizi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwan-e_Shams-e_Tabrizi):

> این خواجه چَرخ است که چون زُهره و ماه است
>   وین خانه عشق است که بی‌حَدّ و کرانه‌ست
>   چون آیِنِه جانْ نَقْشِ تو در دل بِگِرفته‌ست

Here’s a selection of English translations.

> This is the Lord of heaven, who resembles Venus and the moon,
>   This is the house of Love, which has no bound or end.
>   Like a mirror, the soul has received thy image in its heart;
>
> <sub>Reynold A. Nicholson (1898). [*Selected Poems from the Dīvanī Shamsi Tabrīz*](https://archive.org/details/SelectedPoemsFromTheDivaniShamsiTabriz-ReynoldA.Nicholson/page/n57).</sub>

> This is the Master of heaven, who is like unto Venus and the moon, and this is the house of Love, which is without bound and end. The soul, like a mirror, has received your image in its heart;
>
> <sub>A. J. Arberry (1968). [*Mystical Poems of Rumi*](https://archive.org/details/MysticalPoemsOfRumiArberry/page/n71).</sub>

> This is the lord of the sphere:
>       an orb like the Moon or Venus
>   and this is the house of love:
>       boundless, uncontained
>
> Like a mirror to the soul
>   your visage fills the heart
>
> <sub>Franklin D. Lewis (2000). [*Rumi Past And Present, East And West*](https://archive.org/details/RumiPastAndPresent/page/n435). London: Oneworld Publications.</sub>